# Fstream doens't open a file, ofstream does

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

Hi I'am working with two txt files. In the first one, I open the file with fstream, but when I am trying to open the second one with fstream doesn't work, but if I try to open it with ofstream works. Any clue what is going on?. below are the functions. Thanks

```
void stack::read()
{
    string name = "file.txt", line;
    fstream file;
    file.open(name.c_str());//open the file
    char cc;

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Error could not open the file" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //file was opened succesful
        while (file)
        {
            file.get(cc);//get each character of the string
            push(cc);//insert the character into the stack

        }
    }
    file.close();//close the file   
}

void stack::write()
{
    item *r = stackPtr;//point to the top element of the stack
    ofstream file;
    string name = "f.txt";
    file.open(name.c_str());

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Could not open the file" << endl;
        return;

    }
    else
    {
        while (r != NULL)//while r has data write to the file
        {
            file << r->character; //write to the file
            r = r->prev;//move to the prev element in the stack
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Does it exist ?

Comment: `ofstream` is not meant to open a file but create a new one which will be opened afterward.

Comment: Always use appropriate stream types to avoid problems. So when only reading, use `std::ifstream`, when only writing, use `std::ofstream`.

Answer (score 7):

If the file doesn't exist it can be opened with `ofstream` (it will create a new file by that name). But `fstream.open()` with no second parameter assumes read mode and if the file doesn't exist, it won't be opened.

Are you sure you haven't misspelled the file name?